# vim new line at end of file during ifstream input

Tags: c++, vim, fstream

I made some test file for an assignment that I'm doing, but I am not sure why vim is giving me extra characters at the end of file.

So I made an "ABC" file that contains A, B, and C with no new line at the end. So something like

```
vim ABC

AAAABBBCC
```

I outputted a portion of my read code

```
 46    while(1) {
 47       ch = infile.get();
 48       if(infile.eof()) {
 49          break;
 50       }
 51       cout << '~' << ch << '~' << (int)ch << '~' << endl;
 52       v[(int)ch]++;
 53    }
```

and I got

```
~A~65~
~A~65~
~A~65~
~A~65~
~A~65~
~B~66~
~B~66~
~B~66~
~C~67~
~C~67~
~
~10~
```

I am not sure why I am getting a newline character in my input file

Comment: You're probably used to considering the newline character as indicating when you should start a new line. It acts as a separator, like a comma between items in a list. If you have three lines in a file, there should be two newlines. That's part of the Windows/DOS convention. *However,* in the Unix convention, the newline character  doesn't serve as a separator, it serves as a line *terminator.* Whenever you hit the end of a line, you put a newline character. So if you have a file with three lines, it should have three newline characters.

Answer (score 5):

> with no new line at the end

No, you do have a newline character at the end. The newline functions as a line *terminator*, not a line *separator*, which is why even the last line is followed by '\n'.

You can get vim to write an unterminated line with `:set binary noeol`, if you really need to, but it is then no longer what both vim and C++ consider a text file.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the file to be exactly what I written/inputted.

Comment: Note that if you're going to be working with other files, you should solve this problem from the other end -- make your C++ code ignore the line terminator, instead of getting rid of it in your text file.